# Roboearth OpenCV Error

Tags: opencv, roboearth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I haven't been able to save models using *re_object_record record_gui* in the roboearth stack.

I am using ubuntu 12.04 and ros-fuerte.

I am recording the objects without any errors, but when I click on save button, I get the following error

```
OpenCV Error: The function/feature is not implemented (OpenCV was built without SURF support) in cvExtractSURF, file /tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-opencv2-2.4.2-0precise-20120908-1624/modules/legacy/src/features2d.cpp, line 77
caught exception
result = false
```

By looking at a similar question [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/37152/is-roboearth-going-through-an-intense-week-of-migrating-to-fuerte/), I guess that this error might be resolved by linking the correct version of the library, namely **libopencv_nonfree.so**

I am stuck at this point. Do I really need to link opencv nonfree library? If so, how do I link it?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44856/roboearth-opencv-error/) by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 796 on 2012-10-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry about that, please run "svn up" and try it again.

---

Originally posted by [ddimarco](https://answers.ros.org/users/1073/ddimarco/) with karma: 916 on 2012-10-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) on 2012-10-01**:
Thanks ddimarco, this will solve the SURF problem I suppose. I cannot compile the re_vision however, some declarations in the headers are missing. Here is a screenshot [http://i.imgur.com/MzpZh.jpg](https://i.imgur.com/MzpZh.jpg) . I declared getNumberOfPoints() in PatchFile.h, then some warnings and errors emerged.

**Comment by [ddimarco](https://answers.ros.org/users/1073/ddimarco/) on 2012-10-01**:
Please try it again now :)

**Comment by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) on 2012-10-02**:
Okay, thanks again. It's working now